# Url routing out side symfony framework

Tags: apache, symfony, url

If I have a domain lets say somedomain.com which is routed to /var/www/html/symfony/web. Now I want to have a folder "xyz" in /var/www/html and I want somedomain.com/xyz to go to this folder. How will I achieve that in apache2?? Can I do that in a virtual host conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Apache2 vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost :80>
    ServerName somedomain.com
    ...
    Alias /xyz /var/www/html/xyz
```

Now `somedomain.com/xyz` will point to the directory `/var/www/html/xzy`.